# What is a DcmDspRoutine representing in ODX?

Tags: diagnostics, automotive

In ODX there are many different parameters.

What does a DcmDsp Routine represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct mapping between Autosar `DcmDspRoutine` and ODX due to the high flexibility in ODX standard - it depends on the specific authoring guideline of the ODX data.

The `DcmDspRoutine` service (`<DIAG-SERVICE>`) will be defined in ODX, but the exact loacation, structure and how to find this service depends on the used ODX authoring guideline. ie.

- on which layer of the inheritance hierarchy the elements are located
- if any elements are overwritten/eliminated in the inheritance hierarchy
- there could be one `<DIAG-SERVICE>` for `DcmDspRoutine` or there
  could be one `<DIAG-SERVICE>` for each `DcmDspRoutineIdentifier`
- the service could by identified by a specific short-name or by a specific semantic

Below an high-level example how to find the service assuming there is only one `<DIAG-SERVICE>` for `DcmDspRoutine` with the semantic *"ROUTINE-CONTROL"*:

```
+ <DIAG-LAYER-CONTAINER>
  + Collection name of the layers (BASE-VARIANTS/FUNCTIONAL-GROUPS/PROTOCOLS/ECU-VARIANTS)
    + Name of the layer (BASE-VARIANT/FUNCTIONAL-GROUP/PROTOCOL/ECU-VARIANT)
      + <DIAG-DATA-DICTIONARY-SPEC>
        + <TABLES>
          + <TABLE> referenced by a <PARAM>
      + <DIAG-COMMS>
        + <DIAG-SERVICE> with attribute "SEMANTIC" set to "ROUTINE-CONTROL"
          + <REQUEST-REF>
          + <POS-RESPONSE-REFS>
            + <POS-RESPONSE-REF>
      + <REQUESTS>
        + <REQUEST> referenced by a <DIAG-SERVICE>
          + <PARAMS>
            + <PARAM> referencing to a <TABLE>
      + <POS-RESPONSES>
        + <POS-RESPONSE> referenced by a <DIAG-SERVICE>
          + <PARAMS>
            + <PARAM> referencing to a <TABLE>
```

First the `<DIAG-SERVICE>` which maps to `DcmDspRoutine` service need to be found (where the `"SEMANTIC"` attribute matches to *"ROUTINE-CONTROL"*). Within the `<DIAG-SERVICE>` xml node there should be a `<REQUEST-REF>` child-node (which links to the request for `DcmDspRoutine`) and one-or-more `<POS-RESPONSE-REF>` child-nodes (which links to the response for `DcmDspRoutine`). In the `<REQUEST>` and the `<POS-RESPONSE>` xml node, there will be a list of `<PARAM>` xml nodes - each represents one parameter of the PDU and will link to a `<DOP>` or `<TABLE>`. As the `DcmDspStartRoutineIn`, `DcmDspStartRoutineOut`, `DcmDspRoutineStopIn`, `DcmDspRoutineStopOut`, `DcmDspRoutineRequestResOut` may differ for different `DcmDspRoutineIdentifier`, there will be usually a `<TABLE>` referenced that contains all `DcmDspRoutineIdentifier` and their corresponding structures.